# changing a specific field as per file name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 20 files named as nxt_bas_01.txt, nxt_bas_02.txt ... nxt_bas_20.txt and at all the files at line nr.5 i have the same text `TITLE / nxt_bas_01` now i need to change only at line nr.5 as per my file name, i tried with sed -i unsuccessfully, please have a look at my simple code and share your suggestions,

```
num=01
till=20
while [ "$num" -lt `expr $till + 01 ` ]
do
        sed -i '5s/.*/TITLE / nxt_bas_01/' nxt_bas_$num.txt
        num=`expr $num + 1 `
done
```

Comment: `TITLE /` -> `TITLE \/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
for num in {01..20}; do
   sed -i "5s/.*/TITLE \/ nxt_bas_$num/" nxt_bas_$num.txt
done
```

Not tested but it should do the trick.

**Update :**

To replace lines starting with `TITLE /` :

```
 sed -i "s/^TITLE \/.*/yourtext/" yourfile
```

or with the sed `c` command :

```
sed "/^TITLE \// c yourtext" <<< "TITLE /toto"
```

Comment: thanks & great! solved, out of my curious i would like to ask you one more question how tricks would change,imagine                                                                                 case 1: line nr. 5 is not a constant, i need to replace all the lines stating with "TITLE  /"                                                                                                       case2: if i place a variable in a text file lets say $var1

Comment: I updated my answer for case 1 but I'm not sure I understand your needs for case 2. Do you want to replace litteral string `$var1` in your file?